# Console returning first thing Scanner captured without moving onto other blocks of code

Tags: java, cmd

I am trying to write a very simple program which captures a few key pieces of info about a prospective job and inserts those into a prepared cover letter. I have imported Java's scanner utility as you can see in my code. When I run it via the "Java" command in windows' cmd prompt, the first System.out.println command appears and I (the user) input as prompted. But then, the console simply outputs exactly what I input and does not move on to other parts of the code. Also, as you can see, the console only outputs the first word of whatever I input.
I am very new at programming, can anyone spot what I must be missing?

I will include an image of the console here (code below):

[Link to picture - Lack to reputation needed to edit in photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqheW.jpg)

*find code below*

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class CoverLetter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to tera_byteme's Simple Cover Letter Generator.");

        // defines scanner "reader", prompts user to enter business name, stores that in a string var "bizName", closes reader
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the business name.");
        String bizName = reader.next();
        reader.close();

        //same as above block but asks for position title, stores in string var "posTitle"
        System.out.println("Please enter position title.");
        String posTitle = reader.next();
        reader.close();

        //"" but asks for user's name, stores in string var "userName"
        System.out.println("Please enter your name.");
        String userName = reader.next();
        reader.close();

        String seg1 = new String();
        seg1 = "My name is " + userName + " and I am very interested in working for ";

        String seg2 = new String();
        seg2 = bizName + "as a " + posTitle;

        String finalCut = new String();
        finalCut = seg1 + seg2;

        System.out.println("Here is your cover letter!");
        System.out.println(finalCut);


    }
}![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqheW.jpg)
```

Comment: You should wait to close reader until your done with it.  Just keep the last close.  You will also want to use reader.nextLine().

Comment: Hey Jeff! Just tried both of those fixes, and I'm still unfortunately getting the exact same output as originally. Hmm.

Comment: Using `next()` delimits via whitespace by default, which appears to be occurring based on your image. Using `nextLine()` should work. Seems you aren't using an IDE - please post proof that you recompiled after changing to `nextLine()`. You also close the `Scanner` after the first input, which won't allow the `Scanner` to continue scanner over future inputs.

Comment: @VinceEmigh I'm editing the original code now, i'll post the results if I can get image linking to work

Comment: You could copy/paste the text from the console instead of an image.  If you intent 4 spaces it will have a box like code

Comment: @Jeff & ViceEmigh, I changed the code. Here is what happened in the console: 

`D:\JavaProgs>java CoverLetter

Welcome to tera_byteme's Simple Cover Letter Generator.

Please enter the business name.

Business

Business

D:\JavaProgs>`

Comment: @tera-byteme - Don't vandalize your Question by correcting the errors that you were originally asking about,  It makes the Answers look stupid ... and causes other people to say "I just ran the code in your post, it works for me."

Comment: I just ran the code in your post, it works for me. Here's an image (please excuse the size, it's from my phone): ibb.co/kmLSbR  - A few spacing problems, but other than that, it's accepting my input and working as expected

Comment: @VinceEmigh Wow that's so weird. I'm attempting to download an IDE to see if somehow that solves the issue. Eclipse Oxygen doesn't seem to be allowing me to type or input my cursor anywhere...but I can figure that one out. Thanks anyway guys!

Comment: @StephenC He edited the post to suggest he's still experiencing problems with the changes. He should remove/update the image to reflect the changes, but there exists similar problems which makes the post valid (other than the image he posted)

Comment: @StephenC Sorry! I'm new to stackoverflow. Didn't know I wasn't meant to correct my original code as per answers! I will keep that in mind, thanks.

Comment: @StephenC He's still experiencing the issue of the program not accepting input after the first `next` call. The problem still fits the title, he just needs to update/remove the image and update the post with his new results, as well as the specific issue. From what I'm intepreting, the title is focusing on the program ending prematurely.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems  you close your scanner too soon and you use next() instead of nextLine().  Don't forget to recompile!  I tested those fixes and it works for me.  This code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CoverLetter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to tera_byteme's Simple Cover Letter Generator.");

        // defines scanner "reader", prompts user to enter business name, stores that in a string var "bizName", closes reader
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the business name.");
        String bizName = reader.nextLine();

        //same as above block but asks for position title, stores in string var "posTitle"
        System.out.println("Please enter position title.");
        String posTitle = reader.nextLine();

        //"" but asks for user's name, stores in string var "userName"
        System.out.println("Please enter your name.");
        String userName = reader.nextLine();
        reader.close();

        String seg1 = new String();
        seg1 = "My name is " + userName + " and I am very interested in working for ";

        String seg2 = new String();
        seg2 = bizName + " as a " + posTitle;

        String finalCut = new String();
        finalCut = seg1 + seg2;

        System.out.println("Here is your cover letter!");
        System.out.println(finalCut);

    }
}
```

Gives this output:

```
Welcome to tera_byteme's Simple Cover Letter Generator.
Please enter the business name.
Biz Inc.
Please enter position title.
Senior Manager
Please enter your name.
Jeff
Here is your cover letter!
My name is Jeff and I am very interested in working for Biz Inc. as a Senior Manager
```

Comment: @tera - byteme good luck with your program!  If you get it working with the changes that I originally suggested in the comments of your question and also in this answer, feel free to select this as the correct answer by clicking the checkbox next to it.

Comment: @tera - byteme to enter Scanner input in eclipse you can type in the Console view (normally the output area).